# Make MUI select component with no button radius when dropdown is shown

Tags: css, material-ui, frontend

I have MUI select component like this with radius, but when the dropdown shows, the top select box still have radius on bottom corners, how do I set it to 0 when the drop down is clicked.

Also after I click the select box, the background will turn grey, and label will be come orange, how to set the css for that, since I want the background and text color remain the same.
And this is my code

```
<Select
      labelId="select-label"
      id="select"
      multiple={multiple}
      value={selection}
      label={label}
      disabled={disabled}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderValue={(selected: SelectionType) =>
        renderValue(selected, options)
      }
      IconComponent={KeyboardArrowDownIcon}
      disableUnderline
      sx={{
        bgcolor: lxColorsNew.white,
        borderRadius: 2,
        border: `1px solid ${lxColorsNew.orange.main}`,
        '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': { border: 0 },
        '&:hover': {
          bgcolor: lxColorsNew.orange.light,
          boxShadow: `0 0 10px ${lxColorsNew.orange.main}`,
        },
        '&:focus': {
          bgcolor: lxColorsNew.white, 
          '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
            color: lxColorsNew.black,
          },
        },
        '& .MuiSelect-icon': {
          color: lxColorsNew.orange.main,
        },
        '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
          color: lxColorsNew.orange.main,
        },
        '& .MuiFilledInput-root': {
          backgroundColor: lxColorsNew.white,
          '&:hover': {
            borderColor: lxColorsNew.orange.main,
          },
        },
        '& .MuiMenu-paper': {
                borderRadius: '0', // No border radius for the menu paper
                borderLeft: `1px solid ${lxColorsNew.orange.main}`,
                borderRight: `1px solid ${lxColorsNew.orange.main}`,
                borderBottom: `1px solid ${lxColorsNew.orange.main}`,
              },
      }}
      inputProps={{
        MenuProps: {
          sx: {
            '& .MuiMenu-paper': {
              borderRadius: 0,
              borderLeft: `1px solid ${lxColorsNew.orange.main}`,
              borderRight: `1px solid ${lxColorsNew.orange.main}`, 
              borderBottom: `1px solid ${lxColorsNew.orange.main}`, 
            },
          },
        },
      }}
      autoWidth={false}
    >
```

[image]

[image]

[image]